# Cannot login to Visual studio 2019 - Access denied

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, visual-studio-2019

I have instaled the community version which should be free, but it is getting expired. Found out after signing in it should resove the proble, but I get the below issue. How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether the file actually exists?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the folder .IdentityService and sigining it again worked.